# Why the Typed Transaction Needs to Be Encoded to RLP twice in Geth Source Code

Tags: go-ethereum, rlp

I'm working on the Ethereum source code, but I can't understand why the EncodeRLE function in core/types/transaction.go needs to encode typed transaction twice.

```go
// EncodeRLP implements rlp.Encoder
func (tx *Transaction) EncodeRLP(w io.Writer) error {
    if tx.Type() == LegacyTxType {
        return rlp.Encode(w, tx.inner)
    }
    // It's an EIP-2718 typed TX envelope.
    buf := encodeBufferPool.Get().(*bytes.Buffer)
    defer encodeBufferPool.Put(buf)
    buf.Reset()
    if err := tx.encodeTyped(buf); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return rlp.Encode(w, buf.Bytes())
}

// encodeTyped writes the canonical encoding of a typed transaction to w.
func (tx *Transaction) encodeTyped(w *bytes.Buffer) error {
    w.WriteByte(tx.Type())
    return rlp.Encode(w, tx.inner)
}
```

First,  It uses `encodeTyped` method of `tx`, writing the byte represent the  type of transaction as the first byte into `buf`. Then encode `Txdata` to RLP. Secondly, the `buf` that has been encoded is encoded In the final return value again.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The "external" encoding doesn't seems to add much overhead. Perhaps in the future with more transaction types it will make more sense to do things that way.

Comment: Thanks, after reading the EIP-2718, I notice that it may support new transaction types and more coding rules than rlp in the future.  Hence, the "extra" encode may be helpful for expanding ETH.